# Azure Data Factory Expression Query for Copy activity

Tags: azure, copy, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy data from Table storage to another Table storage of a different storage account, for that, I am using Copy activity in Azure data factory.

I want to filter rows that are going to be copied to the sink table storage, for that Azure data factory gives an option to define a query.
I want to apply a filter on the Partition key whose datatype is String but holds numeric values.
I am looking at this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops
there it says that type conversion is implicit for comparison operators like "eq", "le", "ge" etc

So if my query is "`PartitionKey eq 0`" it fails and gives this error:

```
A storage operation failed with the following error 'The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.'.. Activity ID:edf8e608-d25e
```

But if I define my query as "`PartitionKey eq '0'`" it works.

I want to fetch rows with in the certain range of numbers for that I need to cast my partition key to a numeric value, How do I do that?

Also the "`startsWith`" and "`endsWith`" don't work
e.g, this query `PartitionKey startsWith '10'` gives the same error as above.

Looks like this:
[image] 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, to make sure that your query works - you can use **Storage Explorer (preview)** in Azure Portal to build the query in *Query Builder* mode:
[image: Query built with Query builder]

and then switch to *Text Editor*:

[image]

Now, you are sure that you have got **right query**.
Let's apply this query to ADF. Without dynamic content - it will be exactly the same query:
[image]

**In order to create a dynamic query** - we need to add variables or parameters to define the boundary:
[image]

Afterward, create a dynamic content in query field, replacing query:

```
PartitionKey ge '0' and PartitionKey le '1'
```

with the following form using **concat** function:

```
@concat('PartitionKey ge ''0'' and PartitionKey lt ''1''')
```

Notice, that I must enquote single quote (') by adding extra one ('').
In the end - we need just to replace hard-coded values with previously defined parameters:

```
@concat('PartitionKey ge ''',pipeline().parameters.PartitionStart,''' and PartitionKey lt ''',pipeline().parameters.PartitionEnd,'''')
```

That's all. I hope that I explain how to achieve that by building dynamic content (query) in Azure Data Factory.