# Table Storage - dynamics query in Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-storage

In Storage Table I have dynamicaly generated PartitionKey in `YYYY-MM-DD-HH` format. And I need querying this in Data Factory Pipeline

I need something like this:

PartitionKey eq `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHH")`

It is possible? Thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `formatDateTime` dynamic [date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#date-functions) in ADF.

[image]

TEST:

configuration:

[image]

output:

[image]

---

UPDATE:

Sorry for my uncompletely answer.I figured it out by using below expression:

```
@concat('PartitionKey eq ''', variables('dateValue'),'''')
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Entire structure:

[image]

I got some clues from this link,also provide for you:[Azure Data Factory Expression Query for Copy activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56984020/azure-data-factory-expression-query-for-copy-activity).

Comment: OK ... but it is not clear to me how I can link variable into Source query. I'm was try something like this:

PartitionKey eq test (Variable name)
but without success. How I can do it?

Comment: @RadimPluskal Sorry for my uncompletely answer,please see my update answer.